# Iphone route-me application issue

Tags: ios4, route-me

I am using route-me MapView for displaying offline map. It works well in the sample. I followed the Embedding guides and added the MapView.XCodeProj to my Xcode project it compiles successfully. But in my viewcontroller if i add RMMapView view as a subview to main view. It gives an error as "RMMapView refrence not found"

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more information, the exact error output would be helpful, but it sounds like you are missing the libraries.   Make sure that libMapView.a has been added to Target->Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries.

You might want to double check every step of the embedding guides.

Ciao!

-- Randy